# From struct to array

Tags: matlab, data-structures

Let's say I have this structure:

```
Results(i,j).fo
Results(i,j).co
```

where `i=19` and `j=30`. How can I save in a `ixj` matrix all `Results(i,j).fo`? Or even better, How can I say to `bootci` to read only `Results(i,j).fo`

```
Media_tot = mean(Matrix,2)
ci = bootci(1000, @mean, Matrix');
ci = abs(ci' - repmat(Media_tot,1,2));
hE   = errorbar(xdata_m, ydata_m, ci(:,1), ci(:,2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for your first question:

```
reshape([Results.fo], 19, 30)
```

e.g.

```
%// Make a 3x3 matrix of structs with 2 fields
A = [];
for k = 1:9
    A(k).x = k;
    A(k).y = 9-k;
end
A= reshape(A,3,3)
```

Now

```
reshape([A.x], 3,3)

ans =

   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   3   6   9
```

and

```
reshape([A.y], 3,3)

ans =

   8   5   2
   7   4   1
   6   3   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of equivalent structures, e.g.

```
Results = [ struct('fo',1, 'co',2) struct('fo',10, 'co',20); struct('fo',100, 'co',200) struct('fo',1000, 'co',2000) ]
```

You can access all 'fo` using the square brackets

```
all_fo = [Results.fo]
% >> [1 100 10 1000]
```

However, they are then in a 1D-array, to get them in the original format, use

```
all_fo = reshape([Results.fo], size(Results))
% >> [1 10; 100 1000]
```

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?

Comment: Im using a generic `size(Result)` instead of numbers for the `reshape`, otherwise it's the same idea. I din't see your answer on time.